# asp.net mvc5 oauth error with google giving security error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

I can't seem to get google's oauth to work correctly using a pretty much out of the box web site I created with visual studio 2015. I created Project/New Web MVC and deployed to azure so that I would have a real web site with a callback that is a real IP.

I created a key and secret in my Startup.Auth.cs as below:

```
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "xxxog.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "yyy4s3kUzJ"
        });
```

I added the redirect URL in the google console setup as

https://webappazurexxx.azurewebsites.net/signin-google

I've tried to follow Rick Anderson's article here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

And I still get the access_denied error when I try and sign on with google.

http://webappazurexxx.azurewebsites.net/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied

I think it might have to do with I have not enabled OAuth in the google dev console but things have changed since Rick's article and I can't find the new place to do that.

Comment: Paste full error info (or better all 'call back' url from browser), please.

Comment: @LukaszMakowej this is the callback url:  http://webappazurexxx.azurewebsites.net/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied

Comment: It's strange, because should be more, usually there is also error info... Maybe try use Fiddler?

Comment: And double check if you have enabled google+ api in google developer console.